# consistent width layout of child views

Tags: react-native

I am looking for an elegant solution that uses no libraries if possible. I have the following layout which gives me the following UI. I want the columns to have the same size so that Total Vx Value etc are on the same column. For now, the value determines their width. I am guessing flex:1 on children elements don't affect here as I wanted the output to be.

If the screen is too small horizontally, each row can be scrolled to view the hidden prices hence the scrollview in each view container.

what i am hoping to achieve is: Total, VX Value etc to be on the same column.

[image]

```
      <View style={styles.container}>

         <View style={styles.row}>
           <ScrollView
            horizontal={true}
            >

              <View style={styles.size1Children}>
                <Text>Total</Text>
                <Text>10,000.00 USD</Text>
             </View>

             <View style={styles.size1Children}>
               <Text>VX Value</Text>
               <Text>12,893.25 USD</Text>
             </View>

            <View style={styles.size1Children}>
              <Text>Balance</Text>
              <Text>2,893.26 USD</Text>
           </View>

          <View style={styles.size1Children}>
              <Text>Plus Bonas</Text>
              <Text>3,002 USD</Text>
         </View>
     </ScrollView>
    </View>

     <View style={styles.row}>
           <ScrollView
            horizontal={true}
            >

             <View style={styles.size1Children}>
                <Text>Total</Text>
                <Text>0.00 USD</Text>
             </View>

             <View style={styles.size1Children}>
               <Text>VX Value</Text>
               <Text>0.00 USD</Text>
             </View>

            <View style={styles.size1Children}>
              <Text>Balance</Text>
              <Text>0.00 USD</Text>
           </View>

          <View style={styles.size1Children}>
              <Text>Plus Bonas</Text>
              <Text>0.00 USD</Text>
         </View>
     </ScrollView>
    </View>

 </View>
```

my style is:

```
container: {
      flex:1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      padding: 6,
      marginLeft: 1,
      marginRight: 1,
      marginBottom: 3,
      borderBottomColor: 'red',
      borderBottomWidth: 2
    },

    row: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      marginTop: 0,
      height:56,
      padding: 10

    },

    size1Children: {
      flex : 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}` to each of your scroll view like this:

```js
...
<ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}//here   change to flex should work as well
    horizontal={true}
>
...
```

And it should work.